# Unite.vim の action が動かない

Tags: vim

VimFiler を開いて a で action 画面に遷移して
何かしらの action を実行しようとすると、

```
[unite.vim] find              ! -- (file_base)          find this directory(action)
[unite.vim] No such action : do
```

と表示されてしまい、action が実行できません。

gf で find コマンドを実行しようとすると、通常通り実行できるというのと
iTerm で実行ができず、MacVim ですと、問題なく実行が出来ます。

考えられる不具合を教えていただきたいです。

下記僕の .vimrc の中の該当すると思う箇所です。

```
"" Unite.vim
" The prefix key.
nnoremap  [unite] <Nop>
nmap <Leader>u [unite]

" unite.vim keymap
nnoremap <F4> :<C-u>VimFiler<CR>
nnoremap <silent> [unite]u :<C-u>VimFiler<CR>
nnoremap <silent> [unite]c :<C-u>VimFilerBufferDir<CR>
nnoremap <silent> [unite]g :<C-u>Unite<Space>grep<CR>
nnoremap <silent> [unite]b :<C-u>Unite<Space>buffer<CR>
nnoremap <silent> [unite]m :<C-u>Unite<Space>bookmark<CR>
nnoremap <silent> [unite]a :<C-u>UniteBookmarkAdd<CR>
nnoremap <silent> [unite]f :<C-u>Unite<Space>file_mru<CR>
nnoremap <silent> [unite]h :<C-u>Unite<Space>history/yank<CR>
nnoremap <silent> [unite]r :<C-u>Unite -buffer-name=register register<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>vr :UniteResume<CR>

" vinarise
let g:vinarise_enable_auto_detect = 1

" unite-build map
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>vb :Unite build<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>vcb :Unite build:!<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>vch :UniteBuildClearHighlight<CR>

let g:unite_source_grep_command = 'ag'
let g:unite_source_grep_default_opts = '--nocolor --nogroup'
let g:unite_source_grep_max_candidates = 200
let g:unite_source_grep_recursive_opt = ''

" handy keymaps for unite-grep
vnoremap /g y:Unite grep::-iRn:<C-R>=escape(@", '\\.*$^[]')<CR><CR>

"" VimFiler
let g:vimfiler_as_default_explorer = 1
let g:vimfiler_safe_mode_by_default = 0
" Icons.
let g:vimfiler_tree_leaf_icon = ' '
let g:vimfiler_tree_opened_icon = '▾'
let g:vimfiler_tree_closed_icon = '▸'
let g:vimfiler_file_icon = '-'
let g:vimfiler_marked_file_icon = '*'
```

以上です。
よろしくお願いします！！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

同じ問題だと思います。Vim をアップデートしてください。

https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim/issues/1148

Comment: アップデートしたら、無事動作しました。
ありがとうございました！